# How to filter e-mails by Flag status in EWS?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS and trying to find e-mail messages that are flagged for action (i.e. their Flag.FlagStatus property is "Flagged"). I have successfully filtered e-mails based on their subject and other properties, but I just can't wrap my head around how to filter them based on FlagStatus.

The problem arises when defining `$searchFilter` in the code below.
The line returns error

> "Exception calling "FindItems" with "2" argument(s): "Validation
>   failed. Parameter name: searchFilter""

I've tried using other variants of SearchFilter, e.g. SearchFilter+IsEqualTo, but all return the same error.

```bsh
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

$ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP3
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)
$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
$service.Url = "https://mail.server.net/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)

$propertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$propertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text

$searchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Flag.FlagStatus, "Flagged")
$view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1,0)
$messages = $inbox.FindItems($searchFilter, $view)

foreach ($item in $messages.Items) {
    $item.Load($propertySet)
    write-host $item.Flag.FlagStatus
    write-host $item.Body.Text
}
```

This one works:

```bsh
$searchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Categories, "Blue Category")
```

This one doesn't:

```bsh
$searchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Flag.FlagStatus, "Flagged")
```

Comment: Try this `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Flag, $True)`

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately this returns error "Exception calling "FindItems" with "2" argument(s): "The property can not be used with this type of restriction.""

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the Extendedproperty instead of the strongly typed one (which is derived from the ep anyway) eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagFlagStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);

        SearchFilter.Exists sfExits = new SearchFilter.Exists(PidTagFlagStatus);
```

should work to give you any messages that are flagged (eg the property exists) or you could be more specific to get followupFlagged

```
        SearchFilter.IsEqualTo sfEqualTo = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(PidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000002);
```

in `Powershell` you need

```
 $PidTagFlagStatus = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer);
 $searchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Exists($PidTagFlagStatus)
```

or

```
  $searchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo($PidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000002)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for input! Unfortunately I cannot get this code to work. I'm not a professional programmer, but is this surely for Powershell?

`Missing expression after ','.
Unexpected token 'MapiPropertyType.Integer' in expression or statement.`

It might be worthwhile to also mention that the class in question is [ItemFlagStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemflagstatus?view=exchange-ews-api).

Comment: I've added a powershell example post (original is c#)